# How do I create a manipulator with a parameter?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I can't create a manipulator with the parameter, tell me how to implement it.

Writes errors:

The initial value of a reference to a non-constant parameter must be a left-hand value.

Too few arguments in the function call.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char s[] = "Hello, world!\n";

ostream& endp(ostream& stream, int n)
{
    static int count = 0;

    int max_count = 4;

    for (int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (s[i] == '\n')
            count++;

        if (count == max_count) {
            stream << "----------\n";
            count = 0;
        }
    }

    return stream;
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        cout << s << endp(3);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a `stream` argument to the `endp` call - like `endp(cout, 3)`. However, without knowing what you are trying to achieve, it's difficult to explain further what you should do to make your code work. (It's not at all obvious from your code what the intention is!)

Comment: I need to pass the argument to the manipulator, if I add cout, the error "there is no' < < ' operator corresponding to this operand"

Comment: Like I said, you need to tell us what you're trying to do. For example, `cout << s;` followed by `endp(cout,3);` on a separate line will compile, but almost certainly won't give what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to create a stream manipulator that accepts parameters, you need an extra step that your code is currently lacking - you need the manipulator function to not take an `std::ostream` (or `std::istream`) as input, but rather to return a proxy object, and you then need to overload `operator<<` (and/or `operator>>`) to accept that proxy as input.  For example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct endp_s 
{
    int value;
};

endp_s endp(int n)
{
    return endp_s{n};
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const endp_s& in)
{
    // use stream and in.value as needed...
    return stream;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << endp(3);
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/I8kAZo)

If you look at cppreference.com for any of the standard IO manipulators in [`<iomanip>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip), you will see that they all are implemented as standalone functions that return “unspecified” types.  Those are proxy objects that have overloads for `operator<<` and `operator>>`.

Comment: `endp` isn't necessary, you can just do `std::cout << endp_s{3};`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin technically yes. But if you want to follow the same model that the standard library uses, then use wrapper functions for creating the proxies.

Comment: Why would one want to follow that model, what are the benefits?